# MySQL: how do I select Non duplicates from one column without affecting others?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I'd like to be able to pull all the order_ID's in the provided SQL table but rather than just pull them, have it list the amount of Order_ID's to each user that has submitted one such as an example below rather than it list each individual row. From what I read the group_concat would come into play but im a little unsure on the Query.

Lezenko
1,2,3,4,5,7

Mr. Smith
6

Thanks!

Comment: can you add some php in this or just mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `group_concat()` function. You find the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select user_submitted, group_concat(order_id) as order_id from mytable group by user_submitted
```

Comment: That throws out an undefined index :s

Comment: In PHP, here's my code

`code` $query = "SELECT user_submitted, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT order_id) FROM orders_new GROUP BY user_submitted";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $name = $row['user_submitted'];
  $order_id = $row['order_id'];
  
  echo $name . '<br>';
  echo $order_id . '<br><br>';
 }

Comment: @LucasCraven have changed my answer

Comment: Thanks Jens that worked :)
It's listing them as 1,2,3,4 etc... is that all as one string? or is it seperated values that gets printed out?